# JavaScript onChange not firing in IE

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, onchange

I'm trying to get a javascript to run when a dropdown list is changed to specific value, it all works fine in Chrome, but IE just refuses to fire the "onChange" function.

Here is my dropdown list code:

```
<select name="typeTenancy" onchange='TenancyCheck(this.value);' required>
  <option value=""></option>                                                
  <option value="1">1 - Option 1</option>   
  <option value="2">2 - Option 2</option>   
  <option value="3">3 - Option 3</option>
  <option value="4">4 - Option 4</option>
  <option value="5">5 - Option 5</option>                                                           
</select>
```

Here is Javascript i'd like it to run when option 4 is picked:

```
function TenancyCheck(val){
    var element=document.getElementById('tenancyDuration');
    if(val=='4')
    blockReqTenancy();
    else  
    displayTenancy();
}

function blockReqTenancy() {
    document.getElementById("tenancyDuration").style="display:block";
    document.getElementById("tenancyDuration").required=true;
}

function displayTenancy() {
    document.getElementById("tenancyDuration").style="display:none";
    document.getElementById("tenancyDuration").required=false;
}
```

It essentially reveals an input field  when option 4 is selected, but nothing is shown when using Internet Explorer 11.

I have also checked and I've placed the script src within the Body of my HTML code.

If anyone can explain why this is happening and point me in the right direction to resolve this, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Problems like these normally solve themselves once you stop using inline event handlers and instead use standard functions like [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). In any case, use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors.

Comment: @Xufox How would I modify my code to incorporate the addEventListener using a dropdown list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you saying getElementById , your don't have id called "tenancyDuration". You may Add it.

For IE Change your Function a little bit.   like style.display="block";  and use setAttribute function

Full Code

```
<select name="typeTenancy" id ="tenancyDuration" onchange='TenancyCheck(this.value);' required>
 <option value=""></option>                                                
 <option value="1">1 - Option 1</option>   
 <option value="2">2 - Option 2</option>   
 <option value="3">3 - Option 3</option>
 <option value="4">4 - Option 4</option>
 <option value="5">5 - Option 5</option>                                                           
</select>

<script>
function TenancyCheck(val){
  var element=document.getElementById('tenancyDuration');
  if(val=='4')
   blockReqTenancy();
  else  
   displayTenancy();
}

function blockReqTenancy() {
document.getElementById("tenancyDuration").style.display="block";
document.getElementById("tenancyDuration").setAttribute("required", true); 
}

function displayTenancy() {
 document.getElementById("tenancyDuration").style.display="none";
 document.getElementById("tenancyDuration").setAttribute("required", false); 
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the "Tenancy Duration" ID refers to another section within my html that I did not include in my question, apologies for the confusion.

You did however resolve my issue! I changed the syntax from:

.style="display:block";   TO   .style.display="block";

and also for the rest setAttribute etc, and its fixed this on IE! MAGIC.

Comment: I am glad it helped you. Enjoy ! :)